# Magnet falling in copper tube, radial force component

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction, free-fall

Consider a Dipole magnet falling through infinite copper pipe. If we displace a magnet a little bit so that the dipole isn't pointing to the same way as pipe (dipole isn't parallel to the pipe) we get two forces the first one is the component that acts as drag and is slowing down our magnet when falling. But the when magnet is displaced we also get the second force which has a radial (cylindrical symmetry) component.

I can't imagine what this force does to our magnet, and I am surprised because I thought that small radial forces on our displaced dipole are going to add to 0 after integration, but that isn't the case. Why not? Could you explain what is happening here. I can also add some of the calculations if that would be helpful, but I doubt that I have done anything wrong here.

Comment: Interesting question.  I found this paper http://www.msc.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~phyexp/uploads/LaimantParesseux/Tube-Aimant2.pdf you may find interesting but doesn't answer your question directly. I wonder if the drag  or eddy currents also acts as a restoring force that helps reorient and center the dipole and  if the dipole wobbles back and forth with some characteristic frequency as it falls. If the pipe is in vacuum or not might also matter depending on the relative dimensions.

Comment: @UVphoton I find idea of eddy currents reorianting and centering the dipole very interesting. HOw should I approach such a subject? Any ideas?

Comment: Not exactly sure, but if it was an aerodynamics problem you would think about a center of gravity and a center of drag and if they were not in line there would be a righting moment, or if it was a ship you would think of a center of gravity and a center of buoyancy and a metacenter and having a righting moment. In your case if one end of the dipole is closer to the wall it seems like it would induce more eddy currents and drag more, so that side might slow down more making the dipole more vertical. But maybe you could also have unstable situations too.